# Resharper keeps disabling "Show live semantic errors" in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, resharper

How do I keep Resharper from disabling the "Show live semantic errors" & "Underline errors" options in Visual Studio? It seems that whenever I go and manually enable them, they somehow revert back to disabled after some time - I suspect Resharper of doing this. Is there any remedy for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to turn off ReSharper's own code analysis if you want the VS error detection options to be preserved.

To do that, go to ReSharper > Options > Code Inspection > Settings, and deselect "Enable code analysis".

If ReSharper code analysis is on, it turns VS native C# error highlighting off on every initialization. This VS functionality is considered redundant in light of ReSharper's 1k+ own code highlightings.

Comment: I have the same problem as the OP, but I have already turned off this option in resharper.  I still keep losing the "Show live semantic errors" option.

Comment: @chrismay Turns out this is a known issue in ReSharper 6.1.x. The team is expecting to fix this for version 7 that is due this summer. I'm sorry that it's bothering you. Can I ask however what's the reason behind _not_ using ReSharper code analysis that is arguably ReSharper's strongest asset?

Comment: @gorohoroh VS *underlines* the errors in code. VS *adds* the errors to the Error List.

Comment: @JimGreen ReSharper does this as well, and in more sophisticated ways, with [Solution-Wide Errors](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_analysis.html#Solution-Wide_Analysis) and [Find Code Issues](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_analysis.html#Find_Code_Issues)