# How do I turn on 'Show life semantic errors' option automatically with VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, resharper, visual-studio-macros

I'm using resharper with VS2010 and it has the habbit of turning off 'Show life semantic errors' under Tools - Options -Text Editor - C# - Advanced, every time I start up VS2010. I am looking for a simple way to turn it back on (ie a button on a toolbar I can just click).

I thought about making a macro but unfortunately it doesnt record anything beyond:

```
DTE.ExecuteCommand("Tools.Options")
```

I also looked into the commands to see if I can find the command to turn this option on, but no luck.

Anybody got any ideas?

Comment: *"Show life semantic errors"* Is that an attempt to translate to English, or is that actually what your UI says?

Comment: I guess this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7464772/resharper-keeps-disabling-show-live-semantic-errors-in-visual-studio-2010

Comment: Apart from a little typo (it's 'live' not 'life'...oops), that is what the option is called in VS. If you tick that option, the error list window will show all the errors as you type and not wait till you build your project to show them. And it is sort of a duplicate of the above question apart from me not looking to disable resharper's code inspection options, but just looking for a way to easily re-enable the VS option.